# Can someone explain to me scalar fields?

Tags: vector-spaces, scalar-fields

I would like to gain a deeper understanding on scalar fields, especially those which are derived out of vectors. Take for an example a multi-variabled scalar function. The function itself would be a scalar field; however, it is derived from a vector, say $x = \langle x_1, x_2, x_3, \cdots, x_n\rangle$. How would such a field look like? How would you plot such a field?

Comment: Have you read the wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_field) on the subject?
 If so, what do and don't you understand?

Comment: I guess I'm confused in regards to describing a scalar and vector in a Cartesian coordinate system. It is easy to understand that a vector possesses both magnitude and direction. But to differentiate a vector and a scalar in a Cartesian coordinate system seems confusing. A point on the Cartesian coordinate system, as it is plotted with (x,y) this is considered a vector? Why is this so? Also, how would you describe a force as a vector in a similar way? With reference to my question above, how would you plot a scalar field, which is a function of vectors? Where would be the directions here?